# getting a server 500 error during a CORs response

Tags: javascript, cors

I am trying to send a JSON buffer from a Chrome extension but am getting an internal 500 error. Here is the code that sends the buffer.

```js
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onerror = function(req,textStatus,errorThrown) {
    console.log(textStatus);
    alert('on-error')};

    xhr.open('POST', url, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", 'application/json');
    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With",'XMLHttpRequest');
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", '*');
 
    xhr.onload = function () {   //response will go here
        if(xhr.status == 500) {
            alert("server error 500");
        }
```

On the Apache Linux server side, I send back a response with

```
enter code here
       $this->output
            ->set_content_type('application/json')
            ->set_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
            ->set_output(json_encode($table));
```

I have been stuck on this problem for over a month and really need some ideas on what I am doing wrong. I have debuggers on both machines. I see that the buffer is going out correctly and I can see it is being received correctly. I think I am setting the response header correctly but I always get a 500 error. BTW, it works fine with a WAMP running on my localhost.

This is from the apache error_log: [Fri Oct 26 18:22:07.162178 2018] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 2001:tid 139930806171392] [client 69.124.178.164:57141] malformed header from script 'index.php': Bad header: {"0":["{choose}","IOS","Mac","
[Fri Oct 26 18:22:07.163669 2018] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 2001:tid 139930806171392] [client 69.124.178.164:57141] AH01070: Error parsing script headers
[Fri Oct 26 18:22:07.163679 2018] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 2001:tid 139930806171392] (22)Invalid argument: [client 69.124.178.164:57141] AH01075: Error dispatching request to : 
[Fri Oct 26 18:22:33.796554 2018] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 2001:tid 139930797778688] [client 69.124.178.164:57179] malformed header from script 'index.php': Bad header: {"0":["{choose}","IOS","Mac","
[Fri Oct 26 18:22:33.796627 2018] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 2001:tid 139930797778688] [client 69.124.178.164:57179] AH01070: Error parsing script headers
[Fri Oct 26 18:22:33.796633 2018] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 2001:tid 139930797778688] (22)Invalid argument: [client 69.124.178.164:57179] AH01075: Error dispatching request to :

The line that says malformed header is actually my payload from the server to the Extension. Is is not a header, it is the payload.

Comment: so server has an error so is there a server log you can look at?

Comment: Can you share the server log? It is probably not a CORS issue since CORS gives 401

Comment: 500 means there is issue with the server response or probably some error. Check or evaluate your webservice by using postman.

Comment: Note that the `access-control-allow-origin` header is only supposed to be set by the server.  Setting it on the client doesn't do anything.  This isn't the cause of the problem, its just an observation.

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is a *response* header.

Comment: Richard, please provide the response you are receiving from your server. Show network tab from DevTools if possible.

Comment: HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Date: Fri, 26 Oct 2018 18:22:32 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Length: 0
Connection: close
Content-Type: application/text; charset=UTF-8

Comment: My response is too long. How can I paste it in the proper format? [Fri Oct 26 18:22:07.162178 2018] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 2001:tid 139930806171392] [client 69.124.178.164:57141] malformed header from script 'index.php': Bad header: {"0":["{choose}","IOS","Mac","
[Fri Oct 26 18:22:07.163669 2018] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 2001:tid 139930806171392] [client 69.124.178.164:57141] AH01070: Error parsing script headers

Comment: @RichardBernstein Paste it into the question itself, not in the comments.  See the "edit" link right under the question.

Comment: @RichardBernstein what server-side language/framework are you using? Looks like it might be PHP (CodeIgniter or EE or some such?)

Comment: Yes, Daniel, it is CodeIgniter.

Answer (score 4):

Well after over a month of thinking it was my server or my code, it turned out to to be a unconfirmed  bug in codeigniter. I replaced

```
$this->output
          ->set_content_type('application/json')
          ->set_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
          ->set_output(json_encode($table));
```

with direct php calls:

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
echo ($json);
```

Now it works perfectly!